# MDS-00013: no metadata found for metadata object "/WEB-INF/Foo.xml"

Tags: oracle-adf, soa, business-process-management

We have a problem with our application. A single ADF Application that is conneted to 6 different SOA processes with a shared HumanTask.

One of processes is sowing **Error 500--Internal Server Error** when trying to show the content while the other are lunched normaly.

the exeption is -

```
 oracle.adf.controller.ControllerException: ADFC-02001: The ADF Controller cannot find '/WEB-INF/POApproveTask_TaskFlow.xml'.
                at oracle.adfinternal.controller.metadata.provider.mds.MdsMetadataResourceProvider.getMetadataObjects(MdsMetadataResourceProvider.java:466)
                at oracle.adfinternal.controller.metadata.provider.mds.MdsMetadataResourceProvider.loadUnmutalbeMetadataResources(MdsMetadataResourceProvider.java:367)
                at oracle.adfinternal.controller.metadata.provider.mds.MdsMetadataResourceProvider.getResources(MdsMetadataResourceProvider.java:179)
                at oracle.adfinternal.controller.metadata.MetadataServiceImpl.getTaskFlowDefinition(MetadataServiceImpl.java:209)
                at oracle.adfinternal.controller.util.SecurityUtils.invokeURLAllowed(SecurityUtils.java:33)
                at oracle.adfinternal.controller.engine.ControlFlowEngine.invokeTaskFlow(ControlFlowEngine.java:210)
                at oracle.adfinternal.controller.application.RemoteTaskFlowCallRequestHandler.invokeTaskFlowByUrl(RemoteTaskFlowCallRequestHandler.java:99)
                at oracle.adfinternal.controller.application.RemoteTaskFlowCallRequestHandler.doCreateView(RemoteTaskFlowCallRequestHandler.java:64)
                at oracle.adfinternal.controller.application.BaseRequestHandlerImpl.createView(BaseRequestHandlerImpl.java:57)
                at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.createView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:95)
                at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._restoreView(LifecycleImpl.java:831)
                at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:422)
                at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:207)
                at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
                at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:205)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
                at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:128)
                at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
                at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
                at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
                at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:271)
                at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:177)
                at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
                at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.client.worklist.util.WorkflowFilter.doFilter(WorkflowFilter.java:175)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
                at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.client.worklist.util.DisableUrlSessionFilter.doFilter(DisableUrlSessionFilter.java:70)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
                at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:180)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
                at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
                at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
                at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
                at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
                at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
                at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
                at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
                at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
                at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
                at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: oracle.mds.core.MetadataNotFoundException: MDS-00013: no metadata found for metadata object "/WEB-INF/POApproveTask_TaskFlow.xml"
                at oracle.mds.core.MetadataObject.getBaseMO(MetadataObject.java:1408)
                at oracle.mds.core.MDSSession.getBaseMO(MDSSession.java:3874)
                at oracle.mds.core.MDSSession.getMetadataObject(MDSSession.java:1589)
                at oracle.mds.core.MOResolver.getMetadataObjects(MOResolver.java:231)
                at oracle.adfinternal.controller.metadata.provider.mds.MdsMetadataResourceProvider.getMetadataObjects(MdsMetadataResourceProvider.java:413)
                ... 55 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we did a cleanup of some old versions of one of the BPM processes that had that issue, and it workd like charm. 
we still don't know what have happend thue...